# Windows 10 in recovery mode and grub menu isn't showing up

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, usb-installation, recovery-mode

I tried to install Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS in dual boot with windows 10..After the successful installation when I hit enter after removing the usb,the windows booted into recovery mode..grub menu isn't showing.HELP PLEASE
Bios:legacy

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/